# Why does the first forward pass in a neural-network (NN) classification model computes to zero for all classes before final activation?

Tags: neural-networks, weights, cross-entropy

Suppose weights of NN are Gaussian spread initialization then forward pass for all the inputs will evaluate to zero which computes to 0.69 ($-\log_{e}0.5 \approx 0.69 $, since *sigmoid* (0) = 0.5) average loss at least in the first pass. For three classes it would be $1.0986$ ($-\log_{e}\frac{1}{3}$) and so on.

I understand when weights are zero-initialized, but why does this happen when weights are Normally distributed to start with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the weights are zero-initialized, it's certain that you get $-\log 0.5$ in the first batch. In normal, this is not guaranteed, but you'll get similar results on average. Because, on average, each input to logistic regression will be $E[w^Tx+b]=E[w^T]x+E[b]=0$, because $E[w]=E[b]=0$. Actually, each input to sigmoid function is going to be normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance some $\sigma^2$, which can be estimated from your initialization variances for each parameter.

For sigmoidal output, we have the following expected value:
$$E\left[\frac{1}{1+e^{-v}}\right]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-v^2/2\sigma^2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\frac{1}{1+e^{-v}}dv=\frac{1}{2}$$
This integral result can be verified from [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281%2Fsqrt%282*pi*a%29%29*%28e%5E%28-x%5E2%2F%282*a%29%29%29*1%2F%28%281%2Be%5E%28-x%29%29%29+from+-inf+to+inf), which is hard to compute, probably via methods using contour integrals; however, very intuitive if you look at the sigmoid's graph. We normally don't have $E[f(X)]=f(E[X])$, but in this case it holds.

What we're finally interested in is the loss expression, i.e. $E\left[\log\left(1+e^{-v}\right)\right]$, which'll be harder to compute and not available as a theoretical result in wolfram alpha integrator, at least in free version. But, now, it'll give different values according to your initialization variance.

Standardizing your inputs, and using small variances like $1/n$ where $n$ (similar to [Xavier](https://www.deeplearning.ai/ai-notes/initialization/) init.) is the number of neurons will give you approximately $-\log 0.5$ as loss.

Comment: Thanks for the answer it does make sense if I believe the integral. I changed the question a bit to make it more clear because the question was in reference to the first pass. After the first pass, the weights and biases may change then it will not hold. However, what if weights are updated by a constant multiplier of its own weight i.e. $w^{k+1} = w^k - c * \lambda * w^k$, where $c$ is a small enough to not overshadow the weight (This happens when regularization constant ($\lambda$) is higher for $\sum w^2$, as a gradient from the loss may be ignored). Biases are updated as usual.